# How to change grub menu lines order

Tags: grub

How do we change grub menu lines order, as some saying on changing menuentry blocks order of /boot/grub/grub.cfg will do, is contrary to the file in mine ?
How the real correct way to do it?

Comment: Back up grub.cfg. Then copy what entries you want into 40_custom & turn off os-prober so only your entries in 40_custom are used. If you want some entry before your default Ubuntu entry create 06_custom as copy of 40_custom with those entries only. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332570/how-do-i-stop-grub-from-scanning-particular-disks/1332664#1332664

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` with an editor since it is a plain text file.

However, if you install a new kernel, `grub-mkconfig` will be launched and recreate the file using each scripts in `/etc/grub.d` : your modifications will be lost. Then you can add a script in this directory which inserts a menuentry at the right place. It will be harder to change the behaviour of the `10_linux` script which seems to enumerate available Linux kernel starting by the katest.